# How can I rebuild my Android Studio project without saved code?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building an app in android with Android Studio.

In my **styles.xml** I just changed my theme name back to "AppTheme".

But what I forgot to do is to change the theme in the **AndroidManifest.xml**.

And now I get this error and my whole project is errored out:

[image]

When I try to delete the ".NoActionBar" from my style name and then run the project the same thing happens! Android Studio renamed it back to "AppTheme.NoActionBar" and I can't get my project running:
[image]

This is going back to the screenshot I posted above.. I think it does not care about my change and builds the previous one because it still has errors(red marked code) in int(I don't know why my project got redmarked all over after I changed my app theme name).

I also tried changing back the of app theme to "AppTheme.NoActionBar" but then the first theme attribute has the same problem..
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably modifying the **merged** AndroidManifest.xml file. During the build process, the android gradle build plugin generates final AndroidManifest.xml file that may include elements from manifests of included libraries, correct SDK information from your **build.gradle** etc. It's located in `app/build/intermediates/manifest` (app being the name of your module). Since it's a generated file, the changes you make within will be overwritten by the build process each time it's executed. To get rid of the file, execute the project clean task (**Build -> Clean Project)**.

Please make sure you're editing the source AndroidManifest.xml, which is the one in your module's source, probably `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Great answer! Worked perfectly. I din't know that the .xml I edited was overwritten by another ^^ But I think that is a think that Android Studio should fix. It should build with the file I write in Android Studio and not outside.

Comment: Glad that helped, but first of all it's not Studio itself but the gradle android built tools plugin that does this, and secondly it's the only way to go, since you need external entries in your manifest, otherwise any library that contains SDK components such as Services, Activities, BroadcastReceivers etc. wouldn't work. That's how Android build process works.
The newest Android Studio version lets you view the merged manifest - go to your source manifest and see the `Merged Manifest` tab at the bottom. It dislays the exact source of different manifest entries.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name as noActionbar where u have done changes(as AppTheme) or else in the file option there will be smthng like synchronize and validate.try it out see if it works.

Comment: That is what I described at the end. The problem is that one is named as "AppTheme" and the other one as "AppTheme.NoActionBar" in the AndroidManifest and that means that when I change it in my styles I get the same thing with the other attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clean your project with both sides as same name?